# What adjective would you use to describe someone who uses the right vocab consistently?

Tags: adjectives, expressions

I thought of precise, but not entirely sure even after checking a dictionary. Would you think it is the best choice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Precise* is usable in the sense you suggest, but it may be used more often to refer to ways of speaking rather than to accuracy of vocabulary.  For example, I think that the following sentence from the [Agent(The_Matrix)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent_%28The_Matrix%29) wikipedia article refers more to how Agent Gray talks and how he limits what he says, moreso than to vocabulary:

> Like all Agents he is normally dispassionate and aloof, with a precise manner of speaking, but ...

As alternatives to *precise* for speaking of "someone who uses the right vocabulary consistently", consider *[fluent](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fluent)*, "Able to speak a language accurately, rapidly, and confidently".  To some extent, *fluent* emphasizes ease of speech more than accuracy, but a speaker or writer who often uses incorrect vocabulary will not be thought fluent.

Some *fluent* [synonyms](http://dico.isc.cnrs.fr/dico/en/search?b=1&r=fluent&send=Look+it+up) include *articulate, eloquent, facile, flowing, fluid, glib, liquid, mellifluous, silver, silver-tongued, smooth, smooth-spoken, voluble*; of these, a few like *[articulate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/articulate)* (speaking in a clear or effective manner), *[eloquent](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/eloquent)* (effective in expressing meaning by speech) are directly relevant.  Most of the rest emphasize delivery (how one looks and sounds) more than content (what one says), I think.  *Well-spoken*, however, usually refers to content as much as delivery.

*[Literate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/literate)*, "Knowledgeable in literature, writing; literary; well-read" is another word to consider.

Answer (score 5):

I'd concur with jwpat7's suggestion of *[articulate](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/articulate)*, and also like to suggest *[erudite](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/erudite)*, and also some of the synonyms [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/erudite), particularly *[lettered](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lettered)* (and *[literate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/literate)*, as jwpat also mentions).

Answer (score 0):

From the dictionary, I suggest *expressive*.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Two quick things. Firstly, if you are not sure of the answer you should not submit it as one. And secondly, your answer must be supported by appropriate references or your relevant experience. Try to improve your answer using any references or explanation you may have. And finally, you can always delete your answer if you believe that you have answered it incorrectly. Hope to see you here more!

Answer (score 0):

Precise, exact (but not "exacting"), correct.